# How to recover from RAID 5

Tags: raid, data-recovery, raid5

there are 5 disk-array. i've lost the data of one of them. How can i recover? I don't know where to start?

Comment: Start by finding out the make and model of the disks and raid controller.

Comment: Find the doc for your hardware, ultimately, mark the disk as failed, add a new disk as a hotspare to the array, rebuild the array and remove the failing drive.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consult the manual/helpfile for any specifics to the particular RAID controller you have, but essentially you remove the bad disk and replace it with a good one, and that's it.

Or are you saying that you've lost the actual data on the RAID array? In which case the answer is "You restore from your last backup".

Without wanting to sound rude, it's difficult to give a better answer than this until you ask a better question.

Answer (score -1):

Remove broken HDD, install new, add it in RAID managing software.
It will automatically populate it with recovered data, it might take up to 10 hours.

Comment: "it might take up to 10 hours" - I've just had a conversation with an HP tech who lives across the road from me. He's been monitoring a RAID rebuild that's expected to run for at least two weeks.