# How to recover from RAID 5

Tags: ntfs, raid, data-recovery, raid5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover from RAID 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/166555/how-to-recover-from-raid-5)

there are 5 disk-array. i've lost the data of one of them. How can i recover?

Answer (score 1):

**This really belongs on serverfault.**

Before you do anything check the status of your backups.

Assuming you have enough working disks in the array to rebuild: replace the faulty disk with another identical one, and perform a rebuild.

Suggest you read: [Common mistakes while performing RAID recovery](http://www.quetek.com/RAID_mistakes.htm)